# Node "require" syntax create new reference of module

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have those files

/Controller/sub_module/conversation.js

```
var test = [];
function push(){
    test.push(test.length);
}
module.exports = {
    push,
    getTest(){
      return test;
    }
}
```

/index.js (at root)

```
require('../chatserver/Controller/sub_module/conversation').push();//push new item to test variable
```

and then in /Controller/index.js

```
const test1 = require('../Controller/sub_module/conversation').getTest();//return [0]
const test2 = require('./sub_module/conversation').getTest(); //return []
```

test1 and test2 not point to same reference, why ?
Node 8.11.3
IDE Webstorm
[Debug image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bul6k.png)

Comment: am I missing something?  const test1, and const test2--- if ran from the same file - will point to two different files.

Comment: @terary - It's a bit tricky, but if you look closely at the paths, assuming the file is in `Controller` (which the OP says it is), those resolve to the same location.

Comment: I think we will need a full [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), because from what you've posted this doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder push was call in /index.js file

Comment: Goodness gracious. Don't hide things like that. Okay, so now the question is: How are you running `index.js` and `Controller/index.js`? And have you read the [module caching caveats](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_caching_caveats)?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sorry, I have not read this, /index.js will run first ( this will push new item to "test" and then call /Controller/index.js in another synchronous function later )

Comment: @terary I know this is weird, I was update the post with new debug picture.

Comment: This project was debuged on webstorm, node 8.11.3

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I've read your suggested topic and found the answer, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @T.J.Crowder for this : https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_caching_caveats.

I think all relative paths will be converted to absolute paths for name-caching, and in this conversion, the unspecified part of the relative path will be auto-converted to lowercase.

Because that Node will consider

```
require('./sub_module/conversation') //the unspecified part is 'Controller' will be convert to 'controller'
```

same with

```
require('../controller/sub_module/conversation')
```

but different with

```
require('../Controller/sub_module/conversation')
```

Answer (score -1):

`require`d modules shouldn't be used as singleton storages. In node, `require()` returns the same reference to the same module ONLY if the files you're requiring the module from reside in the same directory. Otherwise, even NPM modules are different as detailed in [This post.](http://justjs.com/posts/singletons-in-node-js-modules-cannot-be-trusted-or-why-you-can-t-just-do-var-foo-require-baz-init)